# Pointer to pointer in c,

Tags: c

Thanks for reading this. I have a question. The following code is OK:

```
int main() {
    int x,y;
    int* q;
    int** w;
    x=10;
    y=15;
    q=&x;
    printf("%d\n",*q);
    *w=&y;
    printf("%d\n",**w);
    if(**w<*q){
        printf("asdasdasd%d\n",**w);
    }else{printf("asdasdas%d\n",*q);}
}
```

But this function is bad:

```
void funcio(int* tiempo,int* dni,char* patente,int terminar,int bandera){
    int** tiempom;
    int** dnim;
    char** patentem;
    if(terminar==0){
        if(bandera==0){
            *tiempom=&tiempo; //
            *dnim=&dni; //
            *patentem=&patente; //
            bandera=1;
        }
        if(bandera==1){
            if(**tiempom>*tiempo){
                *tiempom=&tiempo; //
                *dnim=&dni //
                *patentem=&patente; //
            }
        }
    }

    if (terminar==1){
        printf("El dni del chofer con menor tiempo es: %d\n",**dnim);
        printf("Su patente es: %c\n",**patentem);
        printf("Su tiempo fue de: %i\n",**tiempom);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

> warning: assignment to 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
>   warning: assignment to 'char *' from incompatible pointer type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

Thanks for reading <3

Comment: _Au contraire_, your `main` function is bad too. Here: `*w=&y;` should be `w=&q;` (for example). Otherwise, you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer `w`. You are also dereferencing uninitialized pointers a lot in your `funcio` function. This is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: But if a write in the code `w=&q` the console say a warning: warning: assignment to 'int **' from incompatible pointer type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

Comment: And `*w=&x;`  is correct .-.

Comment: `&q` has type `int **` since `q` is a variable of type `int *`, so since `w` is a variable of type `int **`, the assignment `w = &q;` should be valid (it is just assigning an `int **` value to an `int **` variable). `*w=&x;` is correct as long as `w` is a valid pointer, but in the `main` function you posted `w` is uninitialized so `*w = x;` invokes _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You received that warning because you are trying to convert a double pointer(**) to a single pointer(*)

```
void funcio(int* tiempo,int* dni,char* patente,int terminar,int bandera){
    int** tiempom;
    int** dnim;
    char** patentem;

    if(terminar==0){
        if(bandera==0){
            tiempom = &tiempo; //
            dnim = &dni; //
            patentem = &patente; //
            bandera = 1;
        }
        if(bandera==1){
            if(**tiempom > *tiempo){
                tiempom = &tiempo; //
                dnim = &dni; //
                patentem = &patente; //
            }
        }
    }

    if (terminar==1){
        printf("El dni del chofer con menor tiempo es: %d\n",**dnim);
        printf("Su patente es: %c\n",**patentem);
        printf("Su tiempo fue de: %i\n",**tiempom);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm very stressed for a simple problem xD